# How to predict users' preferences using item similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, similarity, recommendation-engine, collaborative-filtering

I am thinking if I can predict if a user will like an item or not, given the similarities between items and the user's rating on items.

I know the equation in collaborative filtering item-based recommendation, the predicted rating is decided by the overall rating and similarities between items.

The equation is:

[image]

[http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?r_{u%2Ci}%20%3D%20\bar{r_{i}}%20+%20\frac{\sum%20S_{i%2Cj}%28r_{u%2Cj}-\bar{r_{j}}%29}{\sum%20S_{i%2Cj}}](http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?r_%7Bu%2Ci%7D%20%3D%20%5Cbar%7Br_%7Bi%7D%7D%20+%20%5Cfrac%7B%5Csum%20S_%7Bi%2Cj%7D%28r_%7Bu%2Cj%7D-%5Cbar%7Br_%7Bj%7D%7D%29%7D%7B%5Csum%20S_%7Bi%2Cj%7D%7D)

**My question is,**

- If I got the similarities using other approaches (e.g. content-based approach), can I still use this equation?
- Besides, for each user, I only have a list of the user's favourite items, not the actual value of ratings.
- In this case, the rating of user *u* to item *j* and average rating of item *j* is missing. Is there any better ways or equations to solve this problem?

Another problem is, I wrote a python code to test the above equation, the code is

```
mat = numpy.array([[0, 5, 5, 5, 0], [5, 0, 5, 0, 5], [5, 0, 5, 5, 0], [5, 5, 0, 5, 0]])
print mat

def prediction(u, i):
    target = mat[u,i]
    r = numpy.mean(mat[:,i])
    a = 0.0
    b = 0.0
    for j in range(5):
        if j != i:
            simi = 1 - spatial.distance.cosine(mat[:,i], mat[:,j])
            dert = mat[u,j] - numpy.mean(mat[:,j])
            a += simi * dert
            b += simi
    return r + a / b

for u in range(4):
    lst = []
    for i in range(5):
        lst.append(str(round(prediction(u, i), 2)))
    print " ".join(lst)
```

The result is:

```
[[0 5 5 5 0]
 [5 0 5 0 5]
 [5 0 5 5 0]
 [5 5 0 5 0]]

4.6 2.5 3.16 3.92 0.0
3.52 1.25 3.52 3.58 2.5
3.72 3.75 3.72 3.58 2.5
3.16 2.5 4.6 3.92 0.0
```

The first matrix is the input and the second one is the predicted values, they looks not close, anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use different similarity functions. For instance, cosine similarity over ratings is common but not the only option. In particular, similarity using content-based filtering can help with a sparse rating dataset (if you have relatively dense content metadata for items) because you're mapping users' preferences to the smaller content space rather than the larger individual item space.

If you only have a list of items that users have consumed (but not the magnitude of their preferences for each item), another algorithm is probably better. Try market basket analysis, such as [association rule mining](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning).

Answer (score 0):

What you are referring to is a typical situation of implicit ratings (i.e. users do not give explicit ratings to items, let's say you just have likes and dislikes).
As for the approches you can use Neighbourhood models or latent factor models.
I will suggest you to read this [paper](http://yifanhu.net/PUB/cf.pdf) that proposes a well known machine-learning based solution to the problem.